# Matching packets in PREROUTING chain in iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, netfilter

I am trying to configure a firewall that will block or change destination of packets based on their content, to be specific - HTTP requests to some pages on some hosts (yeah, that's another "great firewall").
I have no problem with blocking, it is as simple as:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "Host: www.host.com" --algo bm -j DROP
```

The problem is with changing destination address. It is only possible in PREROUTING chain in the nat table. But rules like

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m string --string "Host: www.host.com" --algo bm -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4
```

just never trigger.
I tried to mark packets in PREROUTING chain in mangle table and check for mark in nat/PREROUTING. Packets are marked but never catched in nat/PREROUTING.

Am I doing something wrong (except this whole thing, of course)?

Comment: The answer was placed in serverfault.

http://serverfault.com/questions/693868/why-my-nat-iptables-rules-dont-work-with-marked-packets